# How to add external home directory

Tags: php, ldap

I have a script running which makes users in Active Directory, However the home directories of our employees are on a server. If I try to set the home directory it will only make a local home directory and not a network one.

$ldaprecord['homedirectory'] = $network_path_to_homedirectory;

This is how I set the attribute but it is not doing what I hoped for.

EDIT

This is how it is getting set now.
[image]

But it needs to look likes this:
[image]

The variable $ldaprecord is populated like this:

$ldaprecord['cn'] = $firstname ." ". $lastname;
$ldaprecord['givenName'] = $firstname;
$ldaprecord['sn'] = $lastname;
$ldaprecord['mail'] = $email;
$ldaprecord['userprincipalname'] = $email;
$ldaprecord['samaccountname'] = $shortname;
$ldaprecord['objectclass'][0] = "top";
$ldaprecord['homedirectory'] = "H:\\aponl.local\Shares\Userhome\".$shortname;
$ldaprecord['userAccountControl'] = 544;

Comment: _"This is how I set the attribute but it is not doing what I hoped for."_ - We need a bit clearer explanation than just "not doing what I hoped for". You should include what the path/directory you're adding looks like and explain what does happen and what you expect. It would also help if we knew what you do with `$ldaprecord` once you've populated it. We need a clear picture of what you're doing.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I edited my question with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `homeDirectory` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-homedirectory) gives you the answer:

> If **[homeDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-homedrive)** is set and specifies a drive letter, **homeDirectory** must be a UNC path. Otherwise, **homeDirectory** is a fully qualified local path including the drive letter (for example, DriveLetter**:\Directory**Folder).

In other words, whether it's considered local or remote will depend on the value of the [`homeDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-homedrive) attribute.

So this is what you're looking for:

```
$ldaprecord['homeDirectory'] = "\\\\aponl.local\\Shares\\Userhome\\" . $shortname;
$ldaprecord['homeDrive'] = "H:";
```

Comment: I thought it had something to do with this but could not find the ['homedrive'] attribute for it. Thank you very much. It works like a charm.